# mergeDeepIn() to push an new item to a List in immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/lau_chung/1c2hww9h/4/)

What is the best way to push a new item to `number`, which is a list?

```
var data = {group:{number:[111,222,333]},status:'okay'}
var state = Immutable.fromJS(data)
state = state.mergeDeepIn(['group','number'],[444])
console.log(JSON.stringify(state.toJS()))
```

As you see in the console, the output becomes:

```
{"group":{"number":[444,222,333]},"status":"okay"}
```

Why does `mergeDeepIn()` replace the first item `111` with `444`? I thought it would append `444` to the existing List like this:

```
{"group":{"number":[111,222,333,444]},"status":"okay"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge updates the index with the current value of the merging list.

You have: `[111, 222, 333]` and `[444]`, here

> `[0] = 111` is merged it with `[0] = 444` giving the resulting list
>   as `[444, 222, 333]`.

Also, `mergeDeepIn` is wrapper over `updateIn` (combined with `mergeDeep`) - more details are [here](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/commit/7fadabbb8adddc1d533f705a68a5d9745dcd9eb7#diff-8e3c17da7d27e67665e4db5e90d9096aR1465).